# how to continue numbering in list ordered item inside table using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

The ordered list item inside a table does not continue numbering. When more than one ordered list is added in the first row of the table with numbering continue, the number gets continued. But when a ordered list is added in the second row of the same table with continue, the numbering is not continuing but restarting. Below is the code snippet in css.

```
ol.continue{
   counter-reset: item1;
}

 td ol.continue{
   counter-reset: item1;
 }
```

Comment: Show the HTML as well, please. You can insert a code snippet directly so that we can see the problem.

Comment: CSS Counters are *very* structure specific. If they don't share a parent element they break/reset the counter.

Comment: Here is the HTML 

<tbody>
<tr><td>
<ol start="" class="ol"><li class="li list-item"> text 1</li></ol>
<ol start="" class="ol continue"><li class="li list-item">text 2</li></ol></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<ol start="" class="ol continue"><li class="li list-item"> text 3</li></ol>
<ol start="" class="ol continue"><li class="li list-item">text 4</li></ol></td></tr></tbody>                                                                                     1.Text1 2.Text2 are getting continuous numbering. Text3 should be numbered 3 but it is not. This problem occurs only inside a table